# Carregando link na mesma página, sem refresh!

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, link, text

Galera, boa noite

Preciso de uma ajuda para algo que parece ser muito simples porém não encontrei nada na net que possa ser aplicado. Bom, vamos lá:

Preciso que o conteúdo de um link seja mostrado num campo input na mesma página, sem refresh!

De forma simples, o código da página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title> 
</head>
<body>    
     <a href="#">Valor1</a>
     <a href="#">Valor2</a>
</body>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo "Escrever o valor do link que foi clicado!"?>">

</html>
```

Comment: Esse link está no mesmo domínio que a página ou está noutro dominio?

Comment: no mesmo domínio... vai estar dentro da mesma pasta inclusive!

Comment: Só para ter a certeza do que queres: queres carregar o conteúdo de um ficheiro ou o valor do link somente? e isso queres colocar dentro de um input ou de outra parte da página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito utilizando *JavaScript*. Eu não sei qual é seu grau de conhecimento com *JavaScript* porém eu sou do tipo de cara que gosta de explicar pedaço por pedaço :D

### jQuery

```
$('a').click(function () {
  $('input').attr('value', $(this).text());
});
```

O código acima cria um evento do tipo *click* em todas as tags `<a>` da página (eu não realidade não recomendo isso, pois o certo seria você criar uma **ID** para as âncoras da qual o conteúdo será adicionado ao atributo `value` da tag `<input>`).

Quando o usuário clicar na âncora, o evento procurará por todos os inputs da página e adicionará o atributo `value` correspondente ao valor de `$(this)` da âncora.

### HTML

```
<body>    
  <a href="#">Valor1</a>
  <a href="#">Valor2</a>
  <input type="text">
</body>
```

> Não quero ser chato com isso mas você colocou a tag `<input>` fora de `<body>` isso não é uma boa prática.

Se você quiser dê uma olhada neste link https://jsfiddle.net/iszwnc/1s1t6sko/ para ver o código acima rodando.

## Update

Eu fiz essa modificação utilizando **Classes**. Por quê? Bom eu imagino que você queira pegar o valor de um grupo de âncoras certo? Utilizando **ID** você viola um conceito unitário (digamos assim).

#### Como assim unitário?

A **ID** é um tipo de seletor único, que não pode ser repetido a partir da sua declaração, em outras palavras se você definir uma **ID** para o *Valor 1* você não poderá repeti-la no *Valor 2*.

É ai que entram as **Classes**, com este seletor você consegue repetir infinitas vezes em diferentes *tags* sem violar tal conceito.

> Lembrando que este termo "unitário" não é explicitamente documentado pela **W3C**, eu apenas a utilizei para fins didáticos.

Comment: Show! Excelente... Uma última dúvida: como eu faria para colocar um ID nas âncoras? Realmente tenho outros links na página mas não gostaria que produzissem esse efeito! Obrigado.

Comment: My friend, não rodou aqui no dreamweaver! Veja:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Exemplo</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.your-class').click(function () {
    $('input').attr('value', $(this).text());
    });
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body> 

     <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor1</a>
     <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor2</a>
     <input type="text">
     </body>
     </html>

To rodando no Safari (Macbook)!

Comment: @Felipe você tem que definir a tag `<script>` no final do documento antes do fechamento de `</body>`.

Comment: Assim? Tb nao rodou:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title> 
 
</head>
<body> 

  <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor1</a>
  <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor2</a>
  <input type="text">
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('.your-class').click(function () {
 $('input').attr('value', $(this).text());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Felipe você está importando a biblioteca *jQuery*?

Comment: Não, como faz isso?

Comment: Adicione isso `<script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` antes de `<script type="text/javascript"> $('.your-class').click(function () { $('input').attr('value', $(this).text()); }); </script>`.

Comment: Garoto bão, resolveu todos os problemas! Grande abs...

Comment: Dê uma olhada também [nesse link](http://adrianomaciel.ninja/tutoriais/javascript/javascript-cabecalho-ou-rodape) que explica o porque de colocarmos os `<script>` no final da página.

Comment: como eu faço para por um ID no text e só substituir o valor naquele campo input? Preciso também de uma outra coisa: quando clica no Valor1, o texto precisa ser mudado de cor. Se o usuário depois clicar no Valor2, a cor do campo Valor1 volta ao normal e a cor do Valor2 é alterada. É possível?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem...

Comment: seguinte: preciso que apenas um único campo <input> seja alterado assim que eu clicar nos links. O caso é que tenho vários campos de texto no formulário e isso está atrapalhando. Como ficaria o código abaixo?

HTML:
<body>    
  <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor1</a>
  <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor2</a>
  <input type="text">
</body>

JS:
$('.your-class').click(function () {
 $('input').attr('value', $(this).text());
});

Comment: @Felipe dê uma olhada no código que já está no *JSFiddle* com a alteração que me pediu, espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

Comment: vc é o cara! Já abusando: gostaria de um último ajuste: ao invés de ser informado o texto "Valor1" do campo <a href="#" class="your-class">Valor1</a>, seria possível informar um valor através de um campo dentro do input ("valor_correto")? Ficaria assim: <a href="#" class="your-class" value="valor_correto">Valor1</a>

Comment: @Felipe está pronto! Eu teria usado o atributo `name` mas segundo as recomendações da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a esse atributo está obsoleto a partir da versão 5 do *HTML*.